# How to integrate Lex with webpage

Tags: amazon-lex

I have created a chat bot in aws Lex and wanted to integrate with a webpage. In the Lex console, only Facebook/Twillio/Slack are available, but I have to integrate this with my webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [Greetings, visitor!” — Engage Your Web Users with Amazon Lex](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ai/greetings-visitor-engage-your-web-users-with-amazon-lex/) page?

They have documented pretty much everything and also provided a basic code. Try to play with the code and see if you can accomplish what you want.
If not, come back here and post your doubts.

In [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ai/capturing-voice-input-in-a-browser/) they have shown how to capture voice inputs as well.

All the best.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon Lex has inbuilt support to integrate bots with some platforms such as Facebook, Kik, Twilio, Slack, etc.

If you want to integrate your bot with your own website or mobile apps, then you have two ways:

1. Using AWS SDK: AWS SDK provides APIs to send queries to the bot. This requires a lot of programming knowledge, development, and maintenance efforts.

Refer to this [Lex-Resources link](https://aws.amazon.com/lex/resources/)

This [Doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-a-web-ui-for-your-chatbot/) demonstrates a full-featured Web UI (Amazon Lex Web UI) that provides a Web client for Amazon Lex chatbots.

2. Using third party applications like Kommunicate. It provides a code-less integration with Amazon Lex. It also comes with some cool features such as bot to human handoff and many customization features. Please refer to this [doc](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/integrate-amazon-lex/) for more info